CSRF Token With Laravel Sanctum
Following Laravel docs, when making a request to a laravel backend API that uses Sanctum, the SPA must first make a request to sanctum/csrf-token to get the CSRF token which you must then pass to all other request throught the X-Xsrf header. I've been having issues with this. I am using Axios to fetch data and my SPA is NextJs. when I make a request to Sanctum/csrf-token endpoint, and then check the network tab of my browser console, I see the csrf cookie which contains the Xsrf token. but when I check the storage tab (under application tab), I can't find the cookie, and so I can't use JS to get the token. And also, in some resources, I found out that people do not make request to sanctum/csrf-token, so how do dey get CSRF protection? My question is, is it neccessarry to make a request to Sanctum/csrf-token endpoint or it is not important. If it is important, how do I resolve the issues I mentioned ealier.
I am also using Fortify to handle Login and Registeration
I am using laravel 11
I have tried several solutions to get the cookie but it doesn't work. for example doing document.cookie returns nothing.
And also, I know a walkaround for this is to exempt all endpoints from requiring CSRF protection, but is that safe?
